# Can you load controllers separately and not on page load?

Tags: angularjs

I was just wondering is it possible to run the controllers separately and not all on page load. So like if I'm on a certain page only that controller loads and not others. If I go to a different page then the controller on that page load. I guess it's like a the controller load dynamically. If anyone can find some examples/links/videos that I can refer too, that would be great since I'm having trouble finding them due to my amazing engrish. Thanks.

Comment: id suggesting using Angular's router and/or preferably [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), with [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). this will help modularity of loading controllers and routes.

Comment: Use ozlazyload, it loads the modules dynamically on page loads and inject that module to your app at run time. It can be used with both ng and ui router. https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs

Comment: See this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/IGdbEp7uZh8EjEk4xmOG?p=preview) from [AngularJS ngRoute API Reference - Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example). It shows  page views that load two different controllers - `BookController` and `ChapterController`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ozlazyload, it loads the modules dynamically on page loads and inject that module to your app at run time. It can be used with both ng and ui router. https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs

```
resolve:{
            loadplugin : ["$ocLazyLoad", function($ocLazyLoad){
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name : "modulename",
                    files: ["path/modules/file.js"]
                }])
            }]
        },
```